# Proving a contradiction in Coq

Tags: coq, proof

I'm trying to prove a simple lemma with `Coq`, and I'm having some trouble
ruling out an infeasible case. Here is my lemma:

```
Theorem helper : forall (a b : bool),
  ((negb a) = (negb b)) -> (a = b).
Proof.
  intros a b.
  intros H.
  destruct a.
  - destruct b.
    + reflexivity.
    + (** this case is trivially true *)
```

The relevant sub-goal is trivially true since the assumption `H` is false. How do I tell this to `Coq`?

```
1 subgoal
H : negb true = negb false
______________________________________(1/1)
true = false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there is an assumption which is an equality between distinct constructors (in this case `H : false = true`), you can use `discriminate.`

In other cases, when you have `False` as an assumption, you may use `contradiction.`